# Dynamically Clone ToolStripMenuItem to ContexMenuStrip c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a working `ToolStripMeniItem` menu.

I also have created a `ContextMenuStrip` and assign it to a `PictureBox`

I want to clone/copy the items I have in the `ToolStripMeniItem` to the `ContextMenuStrip`

I have the following code for that:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.pbxPhoto = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.menuView = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
this.ctxMenuView = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);

this.menuView.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.menuImage});
this.menuView.Name = "menuView";
this.menuView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 24);
this.menuView.Text = "&View";

this.menuImage.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.menuStretch,
this.menuActual});
this.menuImage.Name = "menuImage";
this.menuImage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(126, 26);
this.menuImage.Text = "&Image";
this.menuImage.DropDownOpening += new System.EventHandler(this.menuImage_DropDownOpening);

private PictureBoxSizeMode[] modeMenuArray =
{
        PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
        PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
};
private int _selectedImageMode = 0;


private void menuImage_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is ToolStripMenuItem)
    {
        bool bImageLoaded = (pbxPhoto.Image != null);

        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mi in ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).DropDownItems)
        {
            mi.Enabled = bImageLoaded;
            mi.Checked = (this._selectedImageMode == mi.MergeIndex);
        }
    }
}

private void menuImage_ChildClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ToolStripMenuItem)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem mi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        _selectedImageMode = mi.MergeIndex;
        pbxPhoto.SizeMode = modeMenuArray[mi.MergeIndex];

        pbxPhoto.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void DefineContextMenu()
{
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem mi in menuView.DropDownItems)
    {
        //ctxMenuView.Items.Add(mi.Name); // Debug 1 
        ctxMenuView.Items.Add(mi);
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes, if I use the Debug 1 comment line, the code works OK:
[image]

If I use the code above, I got an error:
[image]

Which after the ":" means: The collection was modified; the enumeration operation might not be executed.

What can I do in my code (function `DefineContextMenu()`) to make it transfer the content of the `ToolStripMenuItems` to my `ContextMenuStrip`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a solution. The point is to first create a `ContextMenuStrip` and then assign it to the `DropDown` property of the `ToolStripMenuItem`.

The key code is the following:

```
menuView.DropDown = ctxMenuView;
```

This is because, the `ContextMenuStrip` class is based on the `ToolStripDropDown` class and defines the Items property to hold a collection of `ToolStripItem` instances; the `ToolsStripMenuItem` object is based on the `ToolStripDropDownItem` class, which defines a `DropDown` property that holds a `ToolsStripDropDown` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone some day. I also realized that trying to add the item to the `ContextMenu`. Items was altering the original collection (actually removed that item from the original collection). Using the `AddRange` method worked for me. Since it requires an array of `ToolStripItems`, I just copied each `DropDownItem` into an array then passed that array to the `AddRange` method. You still have to add the `contextMenu` to the `menuView.DropDown` for it to work.

```
private void DefineContextMenu()
{
    ToolStripItem[] toolArr = new ToolStripItem[menuView.DropDownItems.Count];
    int count = 0;
    foreach(ToolStripItem t in menuView.DropDownItems)
    {
        toolArr[count] = t;
        count++;
    }
    ctxtMenuView.Items.AddRange(toolArr);
    menuView.DropDown = ctxtMenuView;
}
```